# How to organize test resource files when using waf

Tags: c++, waf

I am using Google Tests in a project with waf as a build system. I want to know an effective way of dealing with resource files.

For a directory structure like the following:

```
MyProject
├── build
├── src
|   ├──do_something.cpp 
|   ├──do_something.h
├── test
|   ├── unit_test.cpp
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── input1.txt
│   │   ├── input2.txt
├── wscript
```

After building, to run the tests from the build directory, I would need the resource files to be copied across. The build directory would look like:

```
MyProject
├── build
|   ├── test
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   |   ├── input1.txt
│   │   |   ├── input2.txt
│   │   ├── unit_test
```

To achieve this, my current wscript is:

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_cxx')

def build(bld):
    bld.stlib(source='src/do_something.cpp',
              target='mylib',
              includes='src')

    bld.exec_command("cp -r test/resources build/test")

    bld.program(source='test/unit_test.cpp',
                includes='src',
                target='test/unit_test',
                use='mylib')
```

Using the `bld.exec_command` like this seems hacky. What is a better way? How are other people organizing their test resources with waf?

I am using waf 1.9.5.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is of course to change your program so that it can read resources from an arbitrary location. Why litter the file system with multiple copies of the same files?

That said, you can easily copy a directory tree recursively using:

```
for f in ctx.path.ant_glob('tests/resources/**/*'):
    ctx(features = 'subst', source = f.srcpath(),
        target = f.srcpath())
```